# squid blocking access to http and https by IP, but not by domain

Tags: proxy, openvpn, squid

I've been succesfully using openvpn from my Windows 7 laptop whilst connecting to public wifi networks but have come across one network where I can not access the openvpn server as access to any and all sites is blocked if you specify the ip address.

E.g., `http://173.194.65.83` and `https://173.194.65.83` get blocked, but `https://mail.google.com` is fine. (Naturally the block page for the https connection produces a certificate warning.)

A) I am not sure how it is even possible to block the https connections as how does the transparent squid proxy know that the domain being accessed is being accessed by specifying the ip address...

B) Any workarounds?

P.s. reasons for the necessity of openvpn access are (i) privacy, (ii) accessing stuff that may be on ports other than 80/443 such as ssh, (iii) 'cos I want to.

Answer (score 0):

`acl localip dst 192.168.1.0/24
http_access deny localip`

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.